# Getting tag count with Act_as_taggable_on not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I've implemented the acts_as_taggable_on gem and I can see on the db the tag table which tags I have.

I am tagging the model Card, and when I do `Card.tag_counts`

all I get is

```
 [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "test4">, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "you">, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 3, name: "test">, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 4, name: "tyy">, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 5, name: "tetes">]
```

even though I have some cards with the same tag

I've verified this by  `Card.all.map{|c| c.tags}`

and got

```
[#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "test4">], [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "you">,  #ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "test4">], [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 3, name: "test">,  #ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "you">], [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 4, name: "tyy">], [#ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 5, name: "tetes">], [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "you">], [#ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "you">], [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "you">]]
```

so obivously I have a tag for more than once card.

Why won't `Card.tag_counts` show me the count, and if its not the way how can I get the tag_count?

Comment: Try Card.tag_counts_on(:tags)

Comment: that gives me the same result.. see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call `.count` on the returned Tag objects.

ActsAsTaggableOn is using a custom select to return the counts, and when one does that, the selected values (count, in this case) are accessible, but don't show up in inspect.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/185

in order to get all the tag counts you must do something like

```
Card.tag_count.map{|x| [x.name,x.count]}
```

which is pretty ugly...